# Numbers: VALUE function does not recognize empty string

Tags: numbers

I am using Apple Numbers and find it frustrating that cell arguments containing empty text (and sometimes contain numbers from other sheets) are not converted to a number of value 0, when referenced by a function that expects a numeric value.

For example, a function in cell:

```
=MAX(I5,0.5×J5)
```

with J5 being empty, yields an error message

```
The operator “*” expects a number but found “.”
```

So I tried to encase J5 with VALUE(J5), and got another message:

```
VALUE requires a string specifying a number, but found “” instead.
```

Is there an efficient way to treat all spaces as 0 for the countless cells that may have that situation?

Answer (score 1):

```
IFERROR(VALUE(<cell>),0)
```

would return 0 for an empty cell (or any string that can not be converted into a value). I tried something like:

```
= MAX (I5, (0.5 x (IFERROR(VALUE(J5),0)))
```

and my initial tests were working.

Hope this helps

Comment: Although this may work, it is a rather long solution for every argument of a function in every cell that may have the empty string (not entered value) as a parameter. Still looking for a more global solution.

Answer (score 1):

A further suggestion: Select the entire table and set the cell **Data Format** to **"Automatic"**.  Numbers will then determine the data type which may reduce import errors due to cell formatting.  You can also force formatting in the same manner.

[image: Cell Format Setting in Inspector]

I pasted your formula with these settings and got the following result:

[image: Formula result]

If you are uncomfortable/don't like/prefer, you can change the formula to text.

[image: Formula editing]

[image: Text only formula]